# input[type=number] only storing 0 on database (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, html, database, laravel-5

Here is my code:
 my input type number

```
<input type="number" name="numberof" class="form-control" min="1" />
```

my controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $id = Auth::id();

    $userplan=UserPlan::create(['number' => $request['numberof'],
                                'user_id' => $id,
                                'plan_id' => $request['plan'],
                                'date_started' =>\Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')
    ]);
```

It stores data, but the number(data) only stores 0 even if i incremented it.

Comment: What is datatype of `number` column?

Comment: it is just "number"

Comment: try by changing it to `int`

Comment: im sorry, its integer

Comment: is the name of the column in the migration `number` or `numberof` ??

Comment: Have you white listed in model to allow inserting the model. If not then the default value will be set

Comment: paste your migration table create